# How to use Close chat phrases (by operator)?

Tags: chat, omnichannel

In omni-channel, is it possible for operator to use some phrases to close the chat? e.g. "Close Chat Phrases". Thank you

Comment: Can you share more details of the use case and why you would want to go with phrases approach?

Comment: Hey,
We are using SF with telegram bot. Many sessions with operator are finished due to inactive client. We want to give operator a keyword to use when client is inactive. After that the bot will handle if client is inactive or not. cheers

Answer (score 0):

The ability to transfer a session to a bot is currently not available in salesforce. Please consider submitting this as an Idea on [Salesforce IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) so that the product team can implement this in coming releases.

As a workaround, you could up the number of chats an agent can handle to allow for them to keep inactive sessions open for longer.

Similar Ideas:https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000oNSLQA2
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U4e2QAC

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: we already transfer client between TG and SF :) But we want to way to monitor operator messages, and see if operator send timeout phrases for example. cheers

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using the Chat API?

Comment: No, we are not using SF chat api. It will possible using it? Sadly there are too many documentation to understand what is what :)